# Find nested document referred by another ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, mongoose-schema

I have four different document which have same CId which is another id which represents all documents are subset of that ObjectId document.

Master

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238"), "name" : "MyName", "code" : "1234", "__v" : 0 }
```

Subsets

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e72fc28a15d7c1ae0b3de"), "CId" : ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238"), "no_m" : 3, "create_date" : ISODate("2016-12-12T09:50:52.948Z"), "update_date" : ISODate("2016-12-19T14:22:28Z"), "__v" : 0}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e72fc28a15d7c1ae0b3df"), "CId" : ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238"), "no_m" : 3, "create_date" : ISODate("2016-12-12T09:50:52.948Z"), "update_date" : ISODate("2016-12-19T14:22:28Z"), "__v" : 0}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e72fc28a15d7c1ae0b3dg"), "CId" : ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238"), "no_m" : 3, "create_date" : ISODate("2016-12-12T09:50:52.948Z"), "update_date" : ISODate("2016-12-19T14:22:28Z"), "__v" : 0}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e72fc28a15d7c1ae0b3dh"), "CId" : ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238"), "no_m" : 3, "create_date" : ISODate("2016-12-12T09:50:52.948Z"), "update_date" : ISODate("2016-12-19T14:22:28Z"), "__v" : 0}
```

I want to find all documets using monoose in Node.js

My code is

```
var c = 582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238
SubsetSchema.find({'CId' : cid},function(err,Docs){
     if (err)
     {   
         console.log(err);
         return res.status(400).send({"err":err});
     }
     });
     console.log(Docs);
```

But it gives me error

How can I include ObjectId in mongoose find()

with mongodb  db.Docs.find({"CId":ObjectId("582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238")}) working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to cast or use the `ObjectId` constructor here, just pass it as string but also the error you got maybe due to some syntax error, you need to adjust your code to be as follow:

```
var cid = '582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238';
SubsetSchema.find({'CId' : cid},function(err, Docs) {
  if (err)
  {   
     console.log(err);
     return res.status(400).send({"err":err});
  }
  console.log(Docs);
});
```

***First***: Define the variable properly to match where it use `c` to `cid`.

***Second***: Assign it as string by wrap it with single/double quotes.

***Third***: Get the `console.log` statement inside the callback function where `Docs` is defined.

Comment: Moving console log helped... Thanks